# How can i kill an AWS Lambda infirnite loop?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I (embarrassingly) made a mistake in my coding by having a lambda that calls an instance of itself and is now running infinitely and consuming all of our athena sessions....  how can i stop lambda from the console?  help!

Comment: just delete the function, fix it and redeploy.

Comment: Or just update the Lambda function with the fix. The next invocation will execute the new code.

Comment: Just set the concurrency to 0. There is even a big fat button for that in the AWS Lambda management console.

Answer (score 0):

All great answers - thanks so much!  I ended up deleting the function and it ceased the loop.  I found it surprising as i would have thought the function was cached in and running from memory - but guess not:)  Thanks for your help!    I dont know how to mark your replies as "answers" but happy to do so with instructions...

Comment: The Lambda function code may well be cached by the Lambda service for quicker retrieval upon invocation, but when you update or delete the function you are telling the Lambda service not to use the older version any more, so they don't (whether it was cached or not).

Comment: Thanks!  So I didnt need to delete the lambda, I could have just fixed it -- doh!  thanks so much